# Hibernate Criteria API : Projections related confusion

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am using join between multiple tables. I want to retrieve columns from one table only. I tried something like this without success.

```
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.property("b.*"));
```

Getting this exception,

```
could not resolve property: * of: MyClassName
```

Comment: You need to actually specify the column names. If you want them all, then don't use a `Projection`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thank you for your reply. So what can I use if not Projection?

Comment: Specify the actual columns you want.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis 2 questions.

1)I have more than 20 columns. If I mention only couple columns that I need to modify, can I still cast the Object to my class.

2) Is there an alternative to Projection?

Comment: AFAIK 1) Hibernate will return a `List<Object>` containing an object for each column. 2) You can use lazy loading for entity key-mapping columns.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use Criteria API? You can achieve results with just SELECT queries in Hibernate. Could you show more code?